# java:convert java desktop application to servlet

Tags: java, swing, servlets, desktop-application

I am making the java desktop application now I  want to share the some Form of application on the another PC's,I have to use servlet but but I cant found the way to use JFrame Form as it is to Servlet.how can I run it without the browser.

Comment: You can run it using [Java Web Start](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-142562.html). As for using Servlets, I don't believe that Java Swing is a compatible technology, and that while you may be able to keep your "model" code, you'll likely have to hook it to a completely different servlet-compatible view and control. I don't do servlets, so we'll have to wait for experts in this field to corroborate or shoot down my statements and to tell you more.

Comment: You can't directly use the existing JFrame in a web context (unless you deploy via webstart as suggested). Swing components are made to render on the local computer. They have no access to the screen on web user's machine. If you really must make it a Web application you will need to rewrite most of the UI, and I suggest you use vaadin if that truely is your need.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Vaadin. It's the closest thing to "swing for the web" https://vaadin.com/home